# Как в одном приложении получить переменную из второго приложения

Tags: android, переменные

У меня два приложения, в одном я сохраняю `SharedPreferences`. Как я могу обратиться к этой переменной из второго приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обмен данными через `SharedPreferences` возможен, правда это недокументировано.

Почитайте [по ссылке](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Никак, используй [`contentprovider`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/166-urok-101-sozdaem-svoj-contentprovider.html)

Comment: мне как в примере ,в первом приложении,в активити сохранить параметры настроек в этот провайдер, который реализован во втором приложении. Затем во втором приложении уже работать с провайдером, чтобы от туда получать эти данные? я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нет, неверно. `ContentProvider` это то что кажет ваше приложение наружу и любое другое приложение может прочитать эти данные. Например, БД смсок недоступно напрямую, а через `ContentProvider` пожалуйста.

Comment: А если я хочу получить доступ к провайдеру из класса который не наследован от Activity, как это лучше сделать? 
Activity activity = new Activity();
activity.getContentResolver();
?

Comment: "Никак" - неправда. Только данные, сохраненные через MODE_PRIVATE недоступны другим приложениям. Если использовать на пример MODE_WORLD_READABLE, то любое др. приложение сможет прочитать эти данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через **Sticky Broadcast**

Answer (score 0):

В первом ответе было предложено недокументированное  решение . Я пробовал два месяца назад. Смешно но работает . Правда пробовал на рутованом телефоне Попробуйте хотя не думаю что Ваш заказчик это одобрит )